# How to Build Skia on Windows

Tags: c++, skia

I have not yet been able to successfully build skia from source code on Windows 10.  I am going in circles at this point.

I followed the official instructions here https://skia.org/user/build but always get errors.

gn args are:

```
is_official_build=true
is_component_build = false
win_vc="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC"
skia_use_libpng=false
skia_use_icu=false
skia_use_zlib=false
skia_use_libwebp=false
skia_enable_pdf=false
skia_use_libjpeg_turbo=false
skia_use_expat=false
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Development\skia\bin>ninja -C out/Static
ninja: Entering directory `out/Static'
[13/2662] copy ../../../third_party/externals/icu/common/icudtl.dat icudtl.dat
FAILED: icudtl.dat
python C:/Development/skia/gn/cp.py ../../../third_party/externals/icu/common/icudtl.dat icudtl.dat
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
ninja: fatal: ReadFile: The handle is invalid.
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

By the way, first attempt at:

1. using gn or ninja to build anything
2. using Chromium's depot_tools

So, I am not ruling out any user error on my part :(

Comment: The error message says it can't find icudtl.dat. Are you 100% positive it's there?

Comment: It's in there.  In the following path.  "C:\Development\skia\third_party\externals\icu\common\icudtl.dat"

Comment: With all those `..` it looks to me it's supposed to be in `C:\Development\third_party\externals\icu\common\icudtl.dat`

Comment: I think the ninja script that is running is in C:\ Development\skia\bin\out\Static.  So, that would mean that all of the .. take it back to the "skia" directory.  But I don't really understand gn or ninja so I could be wrong about where it is starting from.  Later I'll copy that file to a path directly from C:\Development.  I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: @nada I forgot to mention that I did copy the file to your suggested location.  However, I got the same error code when I tried to build it.  But that is neither here nor there because after pulling the latest skia source code from google I have new errors to deal with.  :|

Comment: You could try ProcMon. It should tell you where the file is being searched.

Answer (score 3):

Skia is painful to build. Use vcpkg to build the binaries you need.

```
> git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
> .\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
> .\vcpkg\vcpkg install skia
```

or

```
> .\vcpkg\vcpkg install skia:x64-windows
```

More info here: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg#quick-start-windows

Comment: Question was about building process of skia

Comment: @olaf: ".\vcpkg\vcpkg install skia" downloads the source code and builds it. The logs and configuration for the build is all there for the pleasure of viewing too. But I'm very confident it's the result ScottS wants, and not fight the same fight as noted by the vcpkg team on building Skia on Windows.